# AWS SNS - Error trying to save Text messaging preferences on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to change Text messaging preferences in the AWS SNS service.

I'm getting this error

```
Invalid parameter: (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 2681ed63-5c47-5bb6-a4c3-beb27367210a)
```

I have 4 clients that use AWS, and I get this error in every client's account.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After 7 days talking with AWS support, I get the solution.

Believe or not, it's simple. The input "Default sender ID" must have only 11 digits.

Why not just say it on error message? ;)

Comment: BTW: The new web AWS Console contains the information about sender Id length limitation.

Answer (score 11):

Or as in my case, I was starting to use SNS in my account for the first time and tried to set USD 5 as the upper limit. The max allowed when you set up the first time is USD 1. Then you've to request AWS Support to increase this limit.